# How do I get the Visual Studio 2012 AddIns folder (or Current User's "Documents" folder) in VS2012 post-build step?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 Extension project with a Post-build step, in which I want to copy the .dll and .AddIn files to the current user's Visual Studio 2012 AddIns folder.

I'm using Windows 8, so the folder I'm trying to copy to is:
"C:\Users\{Me}\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\AddIns"

How can I get the VS AddIns Folder as a VS command-line 'macro' (so I can use something like

```
$(VSAddInsFolder)
```

in my post-build step?

Alternatively, how can I get the current user's Document folder (so I can use something along the lines of:

```
$(MyDocuments)\Visual Studio 2012\AddIns
```

in my post-build step?

The former would be preferable since I imagine the location of the AddIns folder is not the same on all operating systems.

Neither of these seem to be available to me as environment variables (I know I can set the folder up as an environment variables myself, and then use that, but I would rather not if possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the closest I got to answering my own Question!

1) The **VS Add-ins** folder will probably change according to OS.
I only care about Windows 8 at the moment, so I can use `%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\AddIns` as the Add-ins folder.

2) Detect the Windows version in the post-build step, as follows:
(Found [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/c11a9b36-4cf2-4ae4-9d99-7f6a48849384))

```
@echo off
ver | find "6.2" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto Win8

ver | find "6.1" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto Win7

ver | find "5.1" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto WinXP

:Win8
echo Running Windows 8
copy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins\$(TargetFileName)"
copy "$(ProjectDir)$(ProjectName).AddIn" "$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins\$(ProjectName).AddIn"
goto  exit

:Win7
echo Running Windows 7 - I think this Addins path is correct 
copy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins\$(TargetFileName)"
copy "$(ProjectDir)$(ProjectName).AddIn" "$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins\$(ProjectName).AddIn"
goto exit

:WinXP
echo Running Windows XP, so the Addins path might not be correct
copy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins\$(TargetFileName)"
copy "$(ProjectDir)$(ProjectName).AddIn" "$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins\$(ProjectName).AddIn"
goto exit

:exit
```

If I need to run this on different OS's (and they *don't* use the same location for their VS Addins folder), then I can simply adjust the relevant section of the batch file...